# Handle multiple database connection dynamically in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I am doing a research of how to manage the multiple location database server connections dynamically in a ASP.net application.

i have 4 DB servers at different locations (North, East, West & Central, all 4 having different server IPs, there are not fully in charged by my team, so the server IPs or DB login credentials could be changed anytime, they just need to update the new IP or login via a system which stored in Central.)

And my team has more accessibility at the Central (Web & DB server) but we are not allowed to change any code on the system.

One scenario:
Application user want to search some info based on the location. 
A search form will provide a Locations(pulling from Central database) drop down list. 
After selected the location and click on Search button, it will response the result that retrieved from the chosen location DB.

I can only think of the easiest way is to hard-code all the DB connections in web.config. But I tried to avoid hard-coded.

Or every time users trigger a search request, system will trigger a query to Central DB to get the DB server IPs & DB login details. Two queries for each search request.

Is there any other better way to handle this structure and scenario?

There is a high possibility the number of locations will be increasing!

Thanks.

Comment: Given four existing config entries that might extend to say...  a dozen, adding config entries to your web.config file is probably the simplest solution, assuming deployment of the web.config is easier than changes to a database table. Do you have some code in mind already that utilises the web.config?

Comment: How about, on application start get the IPs/Logins and cache or write to a file on your application server. In case of exception like web/db server not found then requery  your central db and update details back. Or deploy a polling service(may be as a windows sevices) which queries at specified intervals and keep your local copy of connections updated.

Comment: Usually, putting values in web.config is not considered "hard coding" them. It's a configuration issues, which can be solved in many ways with different trade offs. I would not be worried about the first query "please give me all available location". It's just one more (quick) query for each user accessing the "query page", separated from the query "give me the data" by the delay required by user to chose. But if you have to setup only one web.config, I would go for that solution: there is no big difference in setting one web.config or setting some values. It actually depends on your scenario

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Code is pretty easy, match the connection name with the chosen value from the drop down list with Case statement. but i may not go for this approach, due to the varies of data.

Comment: @SivaGopal i did think of that way too. Just i wont know when they will add a new location or modify the data. may be use ajax/Json to populate the drop down list.

Comment: You might want to consider at this point whether anyone will ever want to query across _all_ databases

Comment: @GianPaolo Ya, agreed, it is more like a configuration setup. I just try to avoid every time they changed any data/add new locations, i have to manually change it in the web.config, then the change SOP will be triggered(and deployment at midnight).

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid good point, haha.

Answer (score 0):

You already having location table in the central database which you are displaying to the user for selection.

In the Location Table add the column for IP, DatabaseName, UserId & Password.

After selecting Location Name, you generate a dynamic string for connection.

Comment: due to security concern, i try not to expose these info to public.

Comment: You can do this in code behind page. only development person will know. if you keep in web.config then also developer will come to know.